# Gtreamer application with output-selector not working

Tags: gstreamer

I wrote a program to test the output-selector.
Pipeline  i used is

```
                                    --> alsasink  
audiotestsrc --> output-selector --|  
                                    --> alsasink
```

Below is the code

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
GstElement *pipeline, *alsasrc, *outputsel, *alsasink, *alsasink1;
GstPad *sink_pad1, *sink_pad2, *output_sel_pad1, *output_sel_pad2;
setenv("GST_DEBUG","*:3", 1);   

//Gstreamer Initialization
gst_init(&argc, &argv);

//Setting up pipeline and elements
pipeline      = gst_pipeline_new         ("output selector tester");
alsasrc       = gst_element_factory_make ("audiotestsrc",   "alsa source");
alsasink1      = gst_element_factory_make ("alsasink",       "fake sink");
alsasink      = gst_element_factory_make ("alsasink",       "alsa sink");
outputsel     = gst_element_factory_make ("output-selector","output");
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN(pipeline), alsasrc, outputsel, alsasink1, alsasink, NULL);

if(!gst_element_link (alsasrc, outputsel)){
    printf("Error linking");
    return -1;
}

//Input Selector pad settings
output_sel_pad1 = gst_element_get_request_pad (outputsel, "src%d");
output_sel_pad2 = gst_element_get_request_pad (outputsel, "src%d");
sink_pad1       = gst_element_get_static_pad  (alsasink,  "sink");
sink_pad2       = gst_element_get_static_pad  (alsasink1,  "sink");

if(gst_pad_link (output_sel_pad1, sink_pad1) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK){
    printf("Error linking");
    return -1;
}

if(gst_pad_link (output_sel_pad2, sink_pad2) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK){
    printf("Error linking");
    return -1;
}

gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (outputsel), "pad-negotiation-mode", 2, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (outputsel), "resend-latest", TRUE, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT(outputsel), "active-pad", output_sel_pad2, NULL);
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

getchar();

gst_object_unref (pipeline);
return 0;
}
```

But i cant hear any sound.
I tried switching it to other pad also but again no sound.

But when i tried removing either alsasink1 or alsasink from the bin, then its working, switching is happening too and i can hear sound on one pad.

I used the below command to compile the program

```
gcc test.c -o test -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10`
```

Any help will be really great and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below lines before setting pipeline to running state

```
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(alsasink1), "async", FALSE, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(alsasink), "async", FALSE, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(alsasink1), "sync", FALSE, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(alsasink), "sync", FALSE, NULL);
```

and the issue is solved.

When audiotestsrc is used as source, setting "async" to FALSE is enough. But if source is alsasrc then both "async" and "sync" need to be set as FALSE.